# clang disable const propagation

Tags: clang, llvm

I have the following piece of code:

```
int test() {
    int a = 12;
    int b = 13;
    int const z = 134;

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        unsigned v = 11;
        b += v + i + z;
    }
    return a + b;
}
```

I compile it with `clang 4.0` as follows:

`clang -O0 -emit-llvm -S -g myfile.c`

Resulting `myfile.ll` contains the following:

```
entry:
  %retval = alloca %struct.mystruct, align 4
  %a = alloca i32, align 4
  %b = alloca i32, align 4
  %z = alloca i32, align 4
  %i = alloca i32, align 4
  %v = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 12, i32* %a, align 4
  store i32 13, i32* %b, align 4
  store i32 134, i32* %z, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %i, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %i, align 4
  br label %for.cond
  // some more stuff here
for.body:                                         ; preds = %for.cond
  store i32 11, i32* %v, align 4
  %1 = load i32, i32* %v, align 4
  %2 = load i32, i32* %i, align 4
  %add = add i32 %1, %2
  %add1 = add i32 %add, 134 //problem
  %3 = load i32, i32* %b, align 4
  %add2 = add i32 %3, %add1
  store i32 %add2, i32* %b, align 4
  br label %for.inc
  // some stuff here
```

In the code snippet above, `%add1 = add i32 %add, 134` contains propagated `const` value, i.e. `134`. This is not the behaviour I am looking for. I expect it to generate `load` instructions, i.e. something like the following:

```
%3 = load i32, i32* %z, align 4  
%add = add i32 %1, %2
%add1 = add i32 %add, %3
```

Is there any way to disable this kind of behaviour in `clang`?

Comment: This looks like the relevant chunk of code, doesn't look like there's a way to disable this: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/c689f6622f89dba2c01ea03462318006dac4785b/lib/CodeGen/CGExprScalar.cpp#L270-L278

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Ismail Badawi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281108/ismail-badawi) said, this constant propagation is done on the frontend side (Clang) and does not depend on current optimization setting.

As a workaround I suggest you to create a pass that would iterate over instructions, see if they have constant operands and replace them with SSA values that correspond to them (z in your case).